# Unexpected 403 errors on a working server

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server, multiple websites running on it.
http://martion.alomvilag.hu is one of them.

Site is usually working, but from time-to-time it provides a 403 response and Forbidden message:

[image: 403 Forbidden]

I checked error logs, and the only error I found is this:

> (24)Too many open files: [client 66.249.65.89:44991] AH00529: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/' is executable

I checked resources on that and

- no selinux on our system
- `/var`, `/var/www` and `/var/www/martion.alomvilag.hu` are all 755, `.htaccess` is .644

My main concern is that this is only happening sometimes, without pattern and after a refresh or two it is working again. Anyway it is really unpleasant to any of our users. Do you have any advice?

Comment: "Too many open files" is the error you ned to fix. (hint: ulimit)